# Can't connect to AWS RDS MySQL database using internet - but hotspot works

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, networking, firewall

I can't seem to connect to my companies AWS RDS database. The database's security options are open - everyone else in the company can access the database just fine. I'm also able to access the database if I'm on my phones hotspot, but get this error if I use my wifi:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
> 'x.x.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (111)

I'm running Windows 10 with a VM to run Ubuntu. The MySQL or Telnet connection doesn't work on either OS.

Some things I've tried:

-Disable all my Windows firewalls

-Factory reset my router and disable the SPI firewall

-Add port 3306 into inbound and outbound connections on the Windows firewall

-Set my connection to the router as private on Windows

I'll greatly appreciate any help.

EDIT: I'm 99% certain that there is an issue with my internet - perhaps related to the firewall. I don't know anything about networking and can't seem to find many resources online to help with this issue. Not quite sure what else to play around with - I've factory reset the router and disabled the SPI firewall.

Comment: are you using a MYSQL client to connect the RDS?

Comment: @Ali I'm using DBeaver and I've tried connecting to the server using command line too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like DBeaver is not added as a exception to the windows firewall. To add the program to the Windows Firewall Exceptions list, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel
2. Double-click Windows Firewall, and then click the Exceptions tab
3. Click Add Program
4. Locate the file DBeaver.exe (in the program folder, inside Program Files), and then Click OK

After this please try adding restarting DBeaver and try to connect

Comment: DBeaver is running inside my VM. I'm using VMWare Workstation 16. What should I add into the exceptions tab in this case?

Comment: please add VMWare Workstation exe to the exception list

Comment: Hm, still getting the same error. I'm thinking there's something going on with my router/network because I can connect fine to the database if I use my hotspot.

Comment: Usually the routers do not have restrictions for outbound traffic try to restart the windows after this firewall update

Comment: I see. I've tried restarting windows after adding these exceptions & also just disabling all Windows firewalls. Still getting the same error :(

Comment: can you post the screenshot from networking like this one https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/img/ws40_networka2_t.gif

Comment: Since you have selected NAT You might be required to change the advanced setting please refer the doc @ https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/network_nat_details_ws.html#1027150

Comment: I'm certain it has to be a problem with my ISP. I've connected to my modem using my ethernet and still get the same issue, so it isn't my router. The solutions you're suggesting won't work, because I have no problem connecting to my database on the same laptop using my hotspot. Do you have any idea what I could do based on this?